# NoClassDefFoundError when invoking static method of a class by instrumenting byte code

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

I'm trying to invoke a static method whenever an object is being allocated but running into issues. I have reduced my code to smalled working example.

MemorySnifferAgent.java

```
public class MemorySnifferAgent {
    public static void premain(String agentArguments, Instrumentation instrumentation) {
        Callback.main(); //Make sure the class is loaded ?
        instrumentation.addTransformer(new MemoryAllocationTransformer());
    }
}
```

MemoryAllocationTransformer.java

```
public class MemoryAllocationTransformer implements ClassFileTransformer {
    public byte[] instrumentByteCode(byte[] bytecode) {
        ClassReader reader = new ClassReader(bytecode);
        ClassWriter writer = new ClassWriter(ClassWriter.COMPUTE_MAXS);
        CustomClassReader customVisitor = new CustomClassReader(Opcodes.ASM4, writer);
        reader.accept(customVisitor, 0);
        return writer.toByteArray();
    }

    public byte[] transform(ClassLoader loader, String className, Class<?> classBeingRedefined, ProtectionDomain protectionDomain, byte[] classfileBuffer) throws IllegalClassFormatException {
        byte[] bytes = instrumentByteCode(classfileBuffer);
        return  bytes;
    }
}
```

CustomClassReader.java

```
public class CustomClassReader extends ClassVisitor {
    public CustomClassReader(int api, ClassWriter classWriter) {
        super(api, classWriter);
    }

    public MethodVisitor visitMethod(final int access, final String name,
                                     final String desc, final String signature, final String[] exceptions) {
        MethodVisitor methodWritter = super.visitMethod(access, name, desc, signature, exceptions);
        return new CustomMethodWritter(api, name, methodWritter);
    }
}
```

CustomMethodWritter.java

```
class CustomMethodWritter extends MethodVisitor {
    String name;

    public CustomMethodWritter(int i, String name, MethodVisitor methodWriter) {
        super(i, methodWriter);
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public void visitTypeInsn(int opcode, String type) {
        super.visitTypeInsn(opcode, type);
        if (opcode == Opcodes.NEW) {
            super.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKESTATIC, "com/chasingnanos/Callback", "onAllocation", "()V", false);
        }
    }
}
```

Note:

- I realize that tapping into all allocations require tapping all NEW* opcodes and reflection APIs
- super.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKESTATIC, "com/chasingnanos/Callback", "onAllocation", "()V", false); seems to be the problem. Though I'm not able to find what the issue is.

Apologies if it's a very basic question. I'm a newbie to bytecode manipulation.

**Error which I get:**

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError 
 - klass: 'java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is related to the isolation provided by different `ClassLoader`s. Particularly agent's code and "main" code are loaded by different `Classloader`s and thus you can't call your `Callback` from the "main" code. The way to work this around is to move your `Callback` class to a different jar and add it to the bootstrap classpath using  [`-Xbootclasspath/a`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html) option.

See also similar issue at
[Java NoClassDefFoundError when calling own class from instrumented method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4575761/java-noclassdeffounderror-when-calling-own-class-from-instrumented-method)

**Update** (filtering)

If instead of using bootstrap you want to filter out classes that can't access your `Callback`, you probably should do something like this instead of just check for `null`:

```java
public byte[] transform(ClassLoader loader, String className, Class<?> classBeingRedefined, ProtectionDomain protectionDomain, byte[] classfileBuffer) throws IllegalClassFormatException {
    // check if the class inside the loader can access Callback
    // by analyzing its hierarchy of parent class loaders
    for (ClassLoader curLoader = loader; ; curLoader = curLoader.getParent()) {
        if (curLoader == null) {
            System.out.println("Skip '" + className + "' for " + loader);
            return null;
        } else if (curLoader == Callback.class.getClassLoader())
            break;
    }
    byte[] bytes = instrumentByteCode(classfileBuffer);
    return bytes;
}
```

Comment: You are correct !!! Looks like the premain is called by 
sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2 which looks right but transform is called by the bootstrap loader. I added the below snippet to transform and things work. 

 if(loader == null) {
            System.out.println("Transformed by bootstrap loader");
            return null;
        }
        else
            System.out.println("Transformed by " + loader.toString() + " loader");

Any ideas of why the bootstap loader is called at all after the AppClassLoader ?

Comment: I'm not sure I get your question. Does answer "because all classes are loaded lazily (on demand)" satisfies you? I'd also like to warn you that in a complex applications that do their own `ClassLoader`-based magic (e.g. web/app containers) just check for `loader == null` might be not enough

Comment: I'm aware that the classes are loaded lazily but i wasnt sure that bootstrap is called. I thought its called only once before the first invocation of the AppClassLoader.

Comment: You use word "bootstrap" as a noun which in this context makes no sense to me. There is a "bootstrap classpath" and a "bootstrap class loader" in which "bootstrap" is an adjective. And actually "bootstrap class loader" loads a whole bunch of classes. Take a look at `String.class.getClassLoader()`. And which loader would load class is defined not by a moment class is loaded but by its place in the classpath. Actually whole `rt.jar` is by default in bootstrap classpath (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/findingclasses.html) and you are breaking the license if you change it

Comment: It must be emphasized that without filtering, this transformer will be called for *all* subsequently loaded classes, including the classes, it uses itself, e.g. of the ASM library. The error message suggests that even reporting of the failure, i.e. loading `NoClassDefFoundError` itself, failed. Generally, performing an action on *every* allocation without filtering is asking for trouble. If the class `com.chasingnanos.Callback` or one of its dependencies haven’t be loaded yet, they will be instrumented as well, so if `onAllocation()` performs any allocation, you have an infinite recursion.

Comment: My questions has answered with good suggestion for filtering. Tvm.