# Java Instrumentation for URI class: Adding a dependency throws ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, maven, classloader, classnotfoundexception, instrumentation

I have instrumented an URI Constructor to write the created URI to a logshipper. The Logshipper class is part of my Agent Library which is both a maven dependency and a runtime Arg.

The Instrumentation inside the Agent uses a ClassFileTransformer to add the line of code to that constructor. However, when the constructor is called, it throws a ClassNotFoundException with detailMessage: edu/overbeck/masterarbeit/agent/LogShipper. When I take a look in the ClassLoader, the Class is however loaded. A screenshot of my IntelliJ debugger:
![Weird err][1]

Why does this happen? My other instrumented class, ContentLengthOutputStream from the Apache HTTP-core library, works fine with the LogShipper.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vf8b4.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a class loader issue - answered and explained well here: [Java NoClassDefFoundError when calling own class from instrumented method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4575761/java-noclassdeffounderror-when-calling-own-class-from-instrumented-method)
Adding my AgentLib containing the LogShipper class as XBootclasspath helped.